# "Add New Contraints" is disabled (grayed out) for top, bottom, left & right in UICollectionViewCell with 'Content View' enabled

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, constraints

Pictured (fig. 1) is the entirety of the problem for those wishing to use parent-child views-subviews to constraint objects within a UICollectionView schema.  Randomly, in only certain projects, "**Add New Constraints**" (the Tie-fighter symbol) will be **grayed-out** when '**Content View**' is enabled.  If you disable Content View then the objects placed inside the CollectionViewCell get really hard to manage in UI Builder.

Not looking for a programmatic solution.

No, changing Layout to any and all positions for any and all parent and child views doesn't work either (Automatic and Translates Mask Into Constraints are the only two options in XCode 11.5).

[image]

Comment: You don't set constraints on the ***cell*** ... you set constraints on the content.

Comment: Ok thanks @DonMag but the contentView also does not allow 'Add Constraints".  So two levels in a row which aren't allowed, so how do I tell the UICollectionView that my cell is to be constrained to the top and bottom of the CollectionView and with a set width (like 176 pixels)?  I have another old project with a View instead of 'Content View' which allows Add Constraints on the Cell, the View, AND the content-objects.

Comment: For "dynamic sizing cells" your collection view layout determines either the width or height of the cell, and the constraints on the ***subviews*** added to the content view determine the size in the other direction.